# Is there a way to fold with index in Rust?

Tags: indexing, rust, fold

In Ruby, if I had an array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I wanted to get the sum of each element times its index I could do

```rb
a.each.with_index.inject(0) {|s,(i,j)| s + i*j}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do the same thing in Rust? So far, I have

```
a.into_iter().fold(0, |x, i| x + i)
```

But that doesn't account for the index, and I can't really figure out a way to get it to account for the index. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can chain it with [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate):

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let b = a.into_iter().enumerate().fold(0, |s, (i, j)| s + i * j);

    println!("{:?}", b); // Prints 40
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: It if use `.enumerate()` to give me the index in a fold, will it add the arguments after the `acc` and `curr` or before ?