# Generating functions with "hardcoded" index inside it?

Tags: generics, rust

I have to iterate over an array and assign to every index a function with a prescribed signature. I would like to generate a function which knows its index when called.

I would use template values in C++, but this does not work in Rust.

Comment: Showing some sample code, even if it's psuedocode or the equivalent C++, would help us understand your question.

Comment: It rather sounds like you want `for (i, v) in array.iter_mut().enumerate() { *v = function(i); }` See [How to print both the index and value for every element in a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54795989/155423); [How to iterate a Vec<T> with the indexed position?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28991050/155423); [Is there a way to fold with index in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41091641/155423)

Comment: Are you sure you want to generate a closure for every index ? A struct (with its method) is probably what you should use here. Or just define a trait for usize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=36dc331ae2323bc539e688d70aec0583) could serve as a starting point:

```
fn make_fn_for_index(i: usize) -> impl Fn() -> () { // this function returns a function
    move || {
        // move gives ownership of captured variables to closure
        println!("at index {}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arr_of_fns: [Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>; 3] = [
        Box::new(make_fn_for_index(0)),
        Box::new(make_fn_for_index(1)),
        Box::new(make_fn_for_index(2)),
    ];
    for function in arr_of_fns.iter() {
        function();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really quite inefficient compared to `for i in 0..3 { function(i) }`, but OPs request is difficult for me to understand, so maybe it's what they want.

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a3b89626e174b5df2daa1b597914da1f), using unstable const generics...

Comment: Oh I didn't know that const generics are a thing! Cool